# Need to resize pdf on screen

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, pdf

I have 'upgraded' to Windows 8. I often need to compare a Word document with other sources including an original PDF document. Previously I could put each file on a window and resize the windows as needed for comparisons, either small enough to be beside each other, or to flip back and forth. Now the pdf document opens as an 'app' and the only resizing options possible seem to be fullsize (not helpful) or about 3 inches wide at the side of the screen. The latter option is better than nothing but then I cannot bring up the Word window in front - and the overall screen size is reduced so other files cannot be squeezed in.  I do not understand why this 'app' has to be so inflexible. Can someone advise how to open a resizeable PDF?

Answer (score 3):

You can install Adobe Reader (or Acrobat or any other 3rd party reader), and set it as the default program for PDF files.

This will force PDFs to open in desktop mode where you can manipulate it the same way you always have.

Only the Built-in reader app (or an equivalent ModernUI app) will run in the App view.